How to reduce the memory consumption when converting html to pdf?
Please take a look at this:
[..]
String xhtml = convertToXhtml(htmlContent); // memory allocation #1

iTextRenderer.setDocumentFromString(xhtml);// memory allocation #2
iTextRenderer.layout();

ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
iTextRenderer.createPDF(buffer); // memory allocation #3

byte[] encoded     = Base64.getEncoder().encode(buffer.toByteArray()); // memory allocation #4
String pdfAsBase64 = new String(encoded, StandardCharsets.UTF_8); // memory allocation #5

return pdfAsBase64;

I would like to reduce the memory consumption. The first 3 allocation can probably not be avoided, but the last one, creating base64 string should be optimized.
I've tried to use
OutputStream buffer = Base64.getEncoder().wrap(new ByteArrayOutputStream());

but converting OutputStream to String would produce the next memory allocation...

I doubt you can avoid it. But think about do you really need it in form of String? Maybe byte[] is good enough?

I assume you are sending the Base64 string to some other outputstream as well. Why aren't you streaming it directly by wrapping that outputstream with a base64 one?

You should not worry about memory allocations. You have no control over memory managing in Java. What you should worry about creating a big byte array or string in memory that can cause an out of memory error. You are doing both. Do as @M.Deinum and use streaming to create and return the result.

The smallest amount of memory will be used by
ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
iTextRenderer.createPDF(Base64.getEncoder().wrap(buffer));
String pdfAsBase64 = buffer.toString(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);

This will produce Base64 encoded contents in the ByteArrayOutputStream in the first place. Then, the toString method of the ByteArrayOutputStream will pass the internal buffer directly to the String constructor.
Note that any ASCII based character encoding would do, but any other encoding than ISO-8859-1, including ASCII itself would imply checking for non-ASCII characters, which we know aren’t there. ISO-8859-1 is the only one not having such checks as every byte value corresponds to the same Unicode codepoint when interpreted as unsigned number, so it’s the most efficient conversion here.

FWIW, this might save memory, but I'd be suspicious of losing CPU performance.  The intrinsifications around Base64 are extremely effective but sensitive, I'm not sure the streaming versions get the same benefits.

@LouisWasserman the actual encoding operation might be less efficient but the overall operation benefits from having less copying operations and in some scenarios, it may save a garbage collection cycle. It may even make the difference between working and not working when being low on memory. In the end, the developer has to check whether the overall performance is acceptable…
